# How do you make trigger_error in PHP redirect to a specified page?

Tags: php

```
<?php if(!$user->data['is_registered'])
{
    if ($user->data['user_id'] != ANONYMOUS)
    {
        trigger_error('NOT_AUTHORISED');
    }

    login_box('', $user->lang['NOT_AUTHORISED']);
}
?>
```

I am trying to override this code's default actions and just redirect to page of my choice on trigger_rror.

```
<?php if(!$user->data['is_registered'])
{
    if ($user->data['user_id'] != ANONYMOUS)
    {
        trigger_error($redirect="error.php", E_ALL);
    }
}
?>
```

And many variations of it gives no luck. Anyone got an idea for me?

Comment: Do you want to display the error message to the end user or just redirect them on the condition `$user->data['user_id'] != ANONYMOUS`?

Comment: Just redirect them on the condition. The redirect page will explain what happened to them.

Comment: You could use `header('Location: /path/to/error.php');` if that's the case then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to catch the error and redirect if the error's message (`errstr`) is `"NOT_AUTHORISED"`.

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if ($errstr == "NOT_AUTHORISED") {
        // TODO : redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to set up pasetbin one sec... okay I have this so far (I can't figure out how to format code in comment sorry) am I close?

[link]https://pastebin.com/Qm9ZZZ98

Comment: I think you will have a syntax error. Try to change `trigger_error("PLEASE_REGISTER", myErrorHandler);` to `trigger_error("PLEASE_REGISTER")`.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not working. Either because I'm loading the pages dynamically in ajax or because I need to specify the error_handler in phpBB somehow. Will do some googling about how to do that.